# limiting values of a uitextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

! am a newbie in ios.I have a texfield for entering mobile number.And here i have to limit characters to 10 such that the user shouldn't be able to type more than 10 characters. is it possible.please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far?